# XHR upload progress evt.loaded inconsistent behavior

Tags: xmlhttprequest, progress, form-data

I created a progress listener on xhr.upload and tried to display progress using evt.loaded/evt.total. This gives very different results on different browsers and even varies between versions of firefox.

On chrome (Version 34.0.1847.116 m) evt.loaded starts from 0 goes up to total and does this twice(goes back to zero).
On Firefox (24.4.0) evt.loaded goes from 0 to 2x evt.total (evt.loaded>evt.total)! gives 200%
On Firefox (24.2.0) evt.loaded goes from 0 to 2x evt.total sometimes but mostly behaves normally and varies from 0 to evt.total (different behavior on the same browser)!

The files I'm uploading are zip files between 8 to 100 mb.

I find this completely unusable, is there a workaround that would suit all cases? Also what is the cause of this behavior. Finally is this the intended use of evt.loaded and evt.total?